# Using int() errors

Tags: python, int

Can anyone see what is wrong with this code:

```
offset = int((round((width - resize_width) / 2)), int(round((height - resize_height) / 2)))
```

Here is my error message:

```
TypeError: int() can't convert non-string with explicit base
```

Thanks,
LouisP

Comment: Are you intending to pass the result the rightmost call to `int` as an argument to the other?

Comment: Just guessing here but I think you want `(int(round((width - resize_width) / 2)), int(round((height - resize_height) / 2)))` to create a tuple? Pay close attention to those parentheses!

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Some programmer dude you may be right thanks! Will test that

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at your parentheses placement:

```
offset = int(
              ( round((width - resize_width) / 2) ),
              int( round((height - resize_height) / 2) )
            )
```

Your outer call to `int` is given two arguments.  You've passe the second `int(round(...` value as the base argument.  Perhaps you wanted point coordinates?

```
offset = (int(round((width  - resize_width ) / 2)),
          int(round((height - resize_height) / 2))
         )
```